# git checkout from network fileshare

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn, tortoisegit

I have install git and tortoisegit
successfully create a bare repo

location of my network folder
`X:\Test\Test_Source\Test_repo\Test_Repo.git`  --> `bare repo`

These are the folder in my repo

`1. A`
`2. B`
`3. C`

How to checkout only folder `B`?

Comment: git checkout B isn't work ? or did you clone your directory ?

Comment: How to git checkout only folder B?

I only know how to pull out the whole repo.

Comment: `git checkout yourFolderName`  this for remove your changes from local repo ..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Answer (score 0):

You could try these commands:

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo want/checkout/path/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git read-tree --reset -u HEAD
```

Note: TortoiseGit does not support it yet, see [TortoiseGit issue 1599](https://tortoisegit.org/issue/1599).